# Android Navigation Component how to open new fragment without adding it to backStack?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I am doing navigation using the Navigation Component (JetPack). I want to open a new fragment R.id.twoFragment with:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.twoFragment)
```

But I need the R.id.twoFragment not to get into the backStack. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

These 2 lines make the trick works:

```
app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

If you want to go from A to B and expect to finish A:

You need to call B with this action:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA"            
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_call_B"
        app:destination="@+id/fragmentB"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b">


</fragment>
```

If you put log to your fragments you can see that fragmentA is destroyed after calling fragmentB with this action.

Point to Question - As per my knowledge it is not possible to add fragment B without adding it to backstack. When you call action it added automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your `navigation graph`, select the `action` (the conection between the two fragments) and set the property `popUpTo` to indicate where to go when pressing the back button, so :

[image: PopUpTo]

After, be sure to use the action to move between fragments and not the ID of the actual fragment:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.actionFragmentAtoFragmentB)
```

For example, you could indicate that Third fragment popUp to first fragment instead to secondFragment.